# A curious 5x5 square

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you fill a 5x5 grid with numbers from 1 to 5, such that every number occurs exactly once in each row, exactly once in each column and exactly once in each broken diagonal (in both directions)? Note that a broken diagonal is a diagonal line that wraps around the boundaries of the square: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_diagonal

Good luck!

Comment: It seems much clearer to call that *"wraparound diagonal"*. ("Broken diagonal" sounds like the opposite: the non-wrapped-around subset of the diagonal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the following would work

> ```
>  1 2 3 4 5
>  3 4 5 1 2
>  5 1 2 3 4
>  2 3 4 5 1
>  4 5 1 2 3
> ```

Strategy

> The first row is
>
> ```
>  12345
> ```
>
> and each subsequent row is the previous row cyclically rotated two places.

Comment: No way, you did that almost instantly! That is insane speed. It won't even let me accept the answer yet.

Comment: I was about to post this too. I think this is essentially the only solution, up to permuting the digit values, and reflection.

Comment: By the way, I think this method works to fill any NxN square with N numbers, as long as N is coprime to 6.

Comment: #JaapScherphuis I think it only works for prime N greater than 3. For example, can you make it work for N=25?

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky: Yes, it works for 25 too. Assume the top row is in numerical order. One set of diagonals has the numbers in the same order as the top row, and on the other set of diagonals they go in steps of 3. Since 3 is coprime to 25, they also contain all the numbers exactly once.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky And if you use a different row offset than 2, say k, then the diagonals go in steps of k-1 and k+1, and the columns in steps of k. To have all different numbers in the columns and diagonals, you then need k-1, k, and k+1 to be coprime to N. That doesn't help with N that are multiples of 2 or 3, so you might as well stick with the row offset of 2.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky This answer is probably instantaneous for players of renju or gomoku (or other variants of five-in-a-row): the grid of chess knight's moves is often used as a defensive technique, since it blocks the maximum number of opponent's lines, i.e. no two of the defensive plays are on the same line. Here, every number forms exactly such a grid.